# Matching of polynomial coefficients

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I am trying to find the proof of the theorem that states:

> Given two polynomials in $x$, if they are equal to each other, their coefficients must also be equal.

For example, in$$ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d = ex^2 + fx + g,$$

$a$ must equal $0$, and $b$ must equal $e$, etc...

Does anyone have the actual proof stating this?
Thank you!

Comment: What happens if you start giving values to $x$? Set $x=0$, $x=1$...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set $x=0$ and get $0+0+0+d=0+0+g$ so $d=g$. Subtract $d=g$ from both sides, cancel off $x$, and continue...

Comment: Yeah I think this is the proof maybe just note that polynomials by definition have a finite number of non-zero co-efficients

Comment: Thank you!  Exactly what I needed!

Comment: If you cancel x then you can't set it to zero in the next polynomial.

Comment: After you have that d=g, you go back to the original polynomial (the one before x=0) and then you can cancel off x. If you are concerned that x=0 is no longer in the domain, you can know that since it cancels out x=0 is a removable singularity and thus 0 can be reinserted into the domain (we can plug a hole in the graph - we don't have an asymptote).

Comment: If you don't like the reasoning I give here, instead you can move everything to one side of the equation: ax^3+(b-e)x^2+...=0.

Comment: Then you note that the right hand side of the equation (0) has infinitely many roots. A nonzero polynomial can have no more roots than it's degree. Therefore the right hand side must be the zero polynomial. Thus it's coefficients are zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same thing as saying that if a polynomial is equal to the zero polynomial then its coefficients must all be zero. That can be proved a number of ways. For example, if the constant term is not zero, then the polynomial is not zero at zero, so it isn't the zero polynomial; if the constant term is zero, you can factor a power of the variable out of the polynomial to get one where the constant term is not zero, reducing to a problem already solved.

Comment: @J.M., thanks for the edit.

Comment: That's because I care. ;) And apparently I forgot to upvote, so there you go...

Comment: The only reason I didn't choose your answer was because the other answer was more concise.  Thank you for taking the time to answer!

Comment: But when you factor an x and get x*P(x) = 0 you only know that P(x) is zero for all x != 0, so you can't take out the constant in P(x).

Answer (score 0):

In a general field, the Vandemonde determinant tells all.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that term, can you provide me with a reference?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is to start with

$$p(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0\sim b_nx^n+b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+b_1x+b_0=q(x).$$

If I want these to be equal I want their outputs to be equal and in particular at $x=0$:

$$p(0)\overset{!}{=}q(0)\Rightarrow a_0=b_0.$$

Also I want all of their derivatives to be equal if they are to be equal. Direct calculation shows that

$$\begin{align}
p'(x)&=a_1+\mathcal{O}(x)
\\ p''(x)&=2a_2+\mathcal{O}(x)
\\ \vdots&
\\ p^{(k)}(x)&=k!a_k+\mathcal{O}(x),
\end{align}$$
and similarly
$$q^{(k)}(x)=k!b_k+\mathcal{O}(x).$$

Setting 
$$p^{(k)}(0)\overset{!}{=}q^{(k)}(0)\Rightarrow k!a_k=k!b_k\Rightarrow a_k=b_k,$$
for all $k$.